# Implementing threaded message system in php

Tags: php, mysql, messaging

I have a basic private messaging system and I am trying to add a threaded message feature, so the users can msg each other without starting a new msg.
I have two tables one for the messages and the other for the conversation.

What I am actually doing is that I have inbox.php where I show all the messages, then I have view.php where I show the message detail and on that page I have a reply box so if the user sends a reply the new message will be inserted to conversation table with the parent `id` being inserted to `message_id` column in conversation table.

**The problem**

As I said I am inserting the reply message to `conversation` table and now user2 won't be able to see the reply in his inbox as I am fetching that data from `messages` table.

I tried inserting the reply to both `messages` and `conversation` table but that will insert it as a new id and the message_id will be different.

So how would I be able to implement this messaging system where the reply can go to both users?

messages table

```
 id 

 from_user

 to_user

 message

 date
```

conversation table

```
 id 

 from

 to

 message

 message_id

 date
```

Answer (score 0):

Have One table for all your messages and just expand it to accommodate one more field for which message id the message was being sent to.

```
id 

 user

 to_user

 message

 date

 in_reply_to_messageId
```